# Need help in appending a new child to existing XML in php

Tags: php, xml, dom

This is my xml file. I want to add a new element to all books called 'price'. I don't know how to loop through all the books and append a child in them in PHP.
Please help.

```
<book>
<title>title 1</title>
<author>author 1</author>
</book>

<book>
<title>title 2</title>
<author>author 2</author>
</book>
```

Expected output:

```
<book>
<title>title 1</title>
<author>author 1</author>
<price>20</price>
</book>

<book>
<title>title 2</title>
<author>author 2</author>
<price>20</price>
</book>
```

This is what I have written so far:

```
            $dom = new DomDocument;

    $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = FALSE;
    $dom->loadXML($xmlFile);
    $books = $dom->getElementsByTagName('book'); // Find Books

    foreach ($books as $book) //go to each book 1 by 1
    {
        $price = $dom->createElement('price');
        $price  = $dom->appendChild($price );

        $text = $dom->createTextNode('20');
        $text = $dom->appendChild($text);
    }
     $dom->saveXML();
```

Comment: what code have you written so far?

Comment: @MattEllen please have a look at the code

Comment: @MattEllen should $text = $dom->appendChild($text); be $text = $book->appendChild($text);

Comment: Please help is not a question. I don't know **where** you're stuck. I have to figure that out in order to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `PHP` library for `DOM` manipulation is object oriented not functional/ procedural.

You don't generate a `DOMDocument` then use it **everywhere** to call **every method**, each node has it's own methods. You use the DOMDocument to creat new elements but after that you use the element's methods to append an element to another element.

Try to look at the following classes DOMDocument, DOMElement, DOMAttr and DOMText, and their common ancestor DOMNode from the [PHP docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php). That should clear some things up about which kind of object you're dealing with and what methods you can use with it.

```
$xmlFile = '/path/to/filename.xml';
$xmlString = file_get_contents($xmlFile);

$dom = new DomDocument;
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = FALSE;
$dom->loadXML($xmlString);
$books = $dom->getElementsByTagName('book'); // Find Books

foreach ($books as $book) //go to each book 1 by 1
{
    $price = $dom->createElement('price');
    $book->appendChild($price);

    $text = $dom->createTextNode('20');
    $price->appendChild($text);
}
$dom->saveXML();
```

Comment: FYI the loop can all be chained into one line like `foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('book') as $book) $book->appendChild($dom->createElement('price'))->appendChild($dom->createTextNode('20'));` - and even the whole `->appendChild($dom->createTextNode('20'))` part can be dropped if you just pass `'20'` as the second argument to `$dom->createElement('price')`. But +1

Comment: @Dave since r20rock is learning it'd be bad manners for teachers to hand out cryptic textbooks. Yes it can be done, yes i do love using super succint grouping of statements but I've learnt to avoid them for clarity and ease of access when adjusting/ enhancing/ expanding them. As well as some other PHP related optimizations that cannot occur if you heavily rely on nesting functions.

Comment: By the by, if you like method nesting and method chaining that much why not use [that library](http://querypath.org/) it's DOM + jQuery in PHP

Comment: Both the codes are not working :(  should it be just $dom->load($xmlFile);   ??

Comment: Is $xmlFile initialized with the entire text in the XML document? When you do $dom->load($xmlFile) are there any errors? Did you debug?

Comment: @MihaiStancu you are right...the problem is with loadXML .... but my xml file well formatted and also the file exists, I have checked it with file_exists($filename)....any idea about this??

Comment: I edited the example, `DOMDocument::loadXML()` needs a string containing the entire XML document not just an address to a file. If you want to pass the filename as an argument you need to use `DOMDocument::load()`

Comment: @MihaiStancu in your code the foreach loop is iterating properly but the code in the loop is not working (the new children are not being appended)

Comment: Every thing working now :) thanks a lot everyone for your help...I wonder such nice people still breathe on earth :)

Comment: Your XML is not well formed it needs a root element. An XML document does not have multiple top level elements (<book>) just one (i suggest the name <books> perhaps). I shouldn't be the on debugging your code. *Not working* is not a question, show me an error message, show me the `var_dump`s you've read, show me you're actually working and not just waiting for a miraculous fix from a guy who read your mind over the internet.

Comment: @MihaiStancu Thanks for that...I actually had root element as <books> just forgot to write it here. Thanks a lot for your  help...